# I deleted the VisualSVN server folder

Tags: visualsvn-server

Can I ask some help I deleted the VisualSVN server folder. how to create another one ? I don't worry about the deleted folder because it is generated during installation process.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "server folder". If you mean %VISUALSVN_SERVER% (e.g. "C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server") then you can repair this via Control Panel | Programs and features.